# Images are not displayed after sending the email

Tags: marketing-cloud, email, url, bug

I built an email in Marketing Cloud where some pictures have been attached directly from Content Builder (drag-and-drop).

When I send the email, the image is not displayed in most of the different ESPs (sometimes outlook, sometimes Gmail, yahoo... and even after clicking on 'download images on the browser).

[image]

Have you experienced something like this? When I copy-paste the URL of the image directly in the browser (either Chrome or Explorer) the image is displayed properly.

Comment: The URL you paste - is it taken from within MC or source code of email once received in the client?

Comment: It is taken from the source code of the email (the code view)

Comment: Do you see any errors in browser console? ...also if possible can you share the image url or atleast partial URL

Comment: No errors. I can not share the URL by company policy but it ends with https://.../374fcff9-9e9a-4b72-9d3e-41ecc8b875f4.png. I did also some previews in Litmus and it seems that the image is well displayed in mobile but not in desktop. Does it help?

Comment: Are you still experiencing the issue ?  I have experienced a similar behaviour the last friday with some emails. Today I have checked it again and apparently they started working properly again. Perhaps some punctual issue in your MC instance ?  Initially I was thinking in my Emai Content  HTML data volume; that are some limitation inincially. In any case, Ias I told you today is working well apparently.

Comment: I think last week there was a SF issue with that. I dont think there is any known issue now.

Comment: Have you by any chance installed SSL certificates on your Business Unit lately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. The issue was related to a punctual issue in the MC instance. The images are well displayed now.